# Help with parametrization of a Surface and finding tangent plane

Tags: plane-curves

So i have Surface defined as:

$$(x^2+y^2+z^2)^3= (x^2−y^2)^2$$
Where $|x|\leq y$

So I was thinking Spherical Coordinates as base, so something like:

$$x=\cos\theta \cos\phi$$
$$y=\cos\theta \sin\phi$$
$$z=sin\theta $$

And since $$|\cos\theta\cos\phi|\leq \ cos\theta\sin\phi$$

Where should i bound $\theta$, $\phi$

Am i using the correct ideas, or am i doing somethign wrong.
Any isnight would be helpful.
Equation of tangent plane will be kinda trivial, am just having  hard tiem with the parametrization.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting

$$\begin{cases}x&=&r\cos\theta \cos\varphi\\
y&=&r\cos\theta \sin\varphi\\ z&=&r \sin\theta \end{cases}\tag{1}$$

Plugging these relationships into cartesian equation

$$(x^2+y^2+z^2)^3= (x^2−y^2)^2$$

gives, after some computations :

$$r=\pm \cos^2 \theta \cos 2 \varphi \tag{2}$$

(in fact, one can drop the $\pm$ symbol).

Plugging (2) into (1) gives the representation of the surface under the form :

$$\begin{cases}x&=&\cos^3 \theta \cos \varphi\cos 2\varphi\\
y&=&\cos^3\theta \cos 2 \varphi \sin\varphi\\ z&=& \cos^2 \theta \sin\theta \cos 2 \varphi\end{cases}\tag{3}$$

which depends on 2 parameters $\theta$ and $\varphi$.

Answer (score 0):

Your parametrization implies $$x^2+y^2+z^2=1$$

Which alters the equation of surface to $$ (x^2-y^2)^2=1$$

You need to modify your parametrization such that the original surface is not altered.

Comment: ... you should say more explicitly that $r$ is lacking.

Comment: @JeanMarie If I used $r$ then it would mean 3 variables, which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: What kind of parametrization shoud I use then?

Comment: This not a problem : you will have temporarily 3 variables;  one thing is certain : as underlined by @Mohammad Riazi-Kermani, if you write $x=\cos \theta \cos \varphi, $ etc... you constrain your points to belong means to the sphere with radius 1. I am going to give an explicit form.